# Get users that have at least one product code and also more than 10 of the other product code

Tags: sql, sql-server

The table that needs to be queried looks like this:

| ID | UserID | ProductCodes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 33 | 9999 |
| 2 | 456 | 3051 |
| 3 | 456 | 9999 |
| 4 | 456 | 3051 |
| 4 | 33 | 9999 |

How would I write a SQL query to find out which users have at least one productCodes = '9999' and also have more than 10 productCodes <> '9999'?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT
    UserID
FROM dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY 
    UserId
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN ProductCodes = '9999' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 1
AND COUNT(DISTINCT ProductCodes) >= 11
;
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, but I am not looking for the distinct ProductCodes >=11. I need to know if the user has a count of ProductCodes <> '9999' that is greater than  10.

Comment: yes, I understood that, and this code should give you that answer

Answer (score 0):

Use Case or Intersect (case is more performant)

```
SELECT UserID, SUM (case when ProductCodes='9999' then 1 else 0 end) PC9999
, SUM (case when ProductCodes<>'9999' then 1 else 0 end) PCNot9999
FROM dbo.Users
WHERE ProductCodes='9999'
GROUP BY UserID
HAVING SUM (case when ProductCodes='9999' then 1 else 0 end)>0 
AND SUM (case when ProductCodes<>'9999' then 1 else 0 end) >10
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with this. It allows us to get specific with how many times a '9999' product code has been used in comparison with other codes.

```
SELECT
    UserID
FROM Session_Hst
GROUP BY 
    UserID
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN ProductCodes = '9999' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 1
AND COUNT(CASE WHEN ProductCodes <> '9999' THEN 1 ELSE null END ) >= 10
;
```